# How iterate through values in single row in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to go throug all values in single row, process some values if necessary and then return result as string. Something like this

```
 create procedure MyProcedure(@varID int)
  as
  begin
      declare @str varchar(max);
      ---here go loop
      foreach value in (select from table where ID=@varID)
         if(condition1)
           --do something
            set @str=@str+@rez;
         if(condition2)
             --
  end
```

So, I'd like to access somehow each row's value. Can I somehow define cursor over it or something similar?

Comment: Yes, use a cursor. But beware - this is slow.

Comment: I would rather go for some case when in the select, but hard to say with so few code...

Comment: Single row, do you mean you want to process each column in a single row, ie. "select * from table" produces 1 row containing 5 columns with values, you want to process those 5 columns, or that single row?

Comment: Don't do this in the database, do it in your application.

Comment: If this is formatting, as @JNK states, might be easier to do on the front end.

Comment: I want process come columns from one row which id is given as parameter, i.e
select * from table where id=parameter
I want process some columns of that row. 
I've try it in application, but I'm curious how do same in database

Comment: process in what way? do a calculation? create a report? Update the table? It is very vague what you are asking.

Comment: 1) You most likely do _not_ need (or want) a cursor.  
2) You most likely _can_ do this in the DB without it being a performance issue.  
Please see the answer I posted for details on why I mentioned 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mostly just need to shift your thinking around a little and focus on this information, residing in a database, as being a set where you have access to all columns at the same moment in time for a particular row.  So, assuming that the processing logic is not dependent on the order of the columns (as would be the case with the **foreach** concept), but instead can be thought of in terms of being dependent on the order of the rules, you can accomplish this type of thing rather easily and *without* using a CURSOR or any User-Defined Functions (UDFs).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Col1 VARCHAR(50),
    Col2 VARCHAR(50),
    Col3 DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2, 'test', 'bob', '2014-01-10 13:15:45.123');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (5, 'SOMETHING', 'p0t@t0', '2012-10-23 03:23:10.000');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (79, 'another', 'bob', '2013-05-05 23:03:33.111');
GO

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestProc') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE #TestProc;
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #TestProc
(
    @VarID INT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @String = '';

SELECT 
    @String = @String + CASE
                            WHEN LEN(tmp.Col1) > 6 THEN tmp.Col1 ELSE ''
                        END, -- Condition 1
    @String = @String + CASE
                            WHEN tmp.Col2 = 'bob' THEN
                                '~' + UPPER(tmp.Col2) + '~' ELSE ''
                        END, -- Condition 2

    @String = @String + CASE YEAR(tmp.Col3)
                            WHEN 2012 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), tmp.Col3, 101)
                            WHEN 2014 THEN '--' +
                                           CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), tmp.Col3, 131)
                            ELSE ''
                        END -- Condition 3
FROM #Test tmp
WHERE tmp.ID = @VarID;

SELECT @String AS [FinalResult];
GO


EXEC #TestProc 2; -- ~BOB~-- 9/03/1435  1:15:45:123PM
EXEC #TestProc 5; -- SOMETHING10/23/2012
EXEC #TestProc 79; -- another~BOB~
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function within the query and move the conditions to the function and then write the query like

```
SELECT dbo.udf_fun(col1) + dbo.udf_fun(col2) +  dbo.udf_fun(col3) 
from   table 
where  ID=@varID
```